# What is the best practice to write condition when you need to display value even if it zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder which way is better to display the value in case if you got value === 0.

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't look really clean:

`const [value, setValue] = useState(propsValue === 0 ? 0 : propsValue || '');`

I can't write this :
  `const [value, setValue] = useState(propsValue || '');`

because in this case value === false and won't be displayed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to fallback to `''` only if `propsValue` is either `null` or `undefined`.

```
useState(propsValue ?? '')
```

As a side-note, do remember that the parameter you're passing to `useState` is the *initial* value so if the prop value changes, the state will not. If you want the value to update whenever the prop updates, just use the prop value itself instead of an intermediatery state.

Comment: That's awesome.
And I know about the initial value and I use useEffect for that

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for all browsers would be :

`(propsValue !== undefined && propsValue !== null) ? propsValue : ''`

Comment: If OP is using create-react-app >3.3.0, `??` is supported via [`@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) which basically turns `??` into what you've suggested.